# Can't get remote ssh stdout output in cron, but in my terminal it works

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron

I run into an issue last week that drives me crazy. I wrote a BASH script which does a remote ssh connection to acamai and than performs a simple 'ls'. I want to redirect the 'ls' sdtout output to a given file.

While the script itself works like a charm when run manually, it does not while it runs via cron. The cronjob runs as root and each command works as expected expect the ssh command. My System is Gentoo Linux and cron is the old but gold vixie-cron.

To reduce the 200 LOC I put the basics herein which alone (as a single script) are enough to demonstrate the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin'
#set -x
shopt -s lastpipe
exec 2>log.out
(ssh -i <path to key> -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <account@example.com> 'ls -r <path>') > '/root/listing.txt'
```

Even in `-vvv` debug mode of `ssh` I can see, that everything works...just except that I get no stdout output.
Than I tried something else that I found in another posting on the internet:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin'
#set -x
shopt -s lastpipe
exec 2>log.out
(ssh -T -i <path to key> -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <account@example.com> 'ls -r <path>' </dev/zero) > '/root/listing.txt'
```

Drawback here, I start a ssh session that I can't close and I guess its due to /dev/zero.
Another approach was to TEE Pipe the sub-shell of the ssh command...this worked for a short time ( and why not yet anymore ?!)

Now I'm clueless and need help. Cron has its PATH, uses BASH etc. Curious my boss did that with success with java (and he hates BASH...).

Any explanation and helpful tips are greatly welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get no stdout output"?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-tt` to your ssh command to force a pseudo-terminal to be allocated?

Comment: Also, are you saying that the cron successfully connects through ssh and the problem is that you're not getting stdout? Or are you saying that the ssh connection itself fails?

Comment: Does this problem only happen when you call `ls` or does it exist when you replace `ls` with another command such as `date` too? Are you sure whatever user cron runs as has write permission to `/root/listing.txt`? What if you write the output to some other file that you KNOW everyone has access to?

Comment: in your snippet the subshell parentheses around ssh are not needed. are you sure the code is run in bash, not in /bin/sh where they don't work?

Comment: In crontab, add this at the end of your command:  `>/tmp/out 2>/tmp/out2` and look at these.  You might see some error messages.  And put `#!bin/bash -x` on your script to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @sripley Yes I did, and regarding to cron, yes it has a 100% successful connection (-vvv is my friend).

Comment: @Nic3500 I did that with an built in exec

Comment: Totally strange, I readded my script to cron but this time I scheduled it for each hour....and it works. While I had the issues above, I run it each minute (to see what happens). Could it be that akamai has some sort of command limitation ??? But still it does not explain why the script works always via BASH.

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue, I make script for CRON and it gets output from remote SSH host. 
If i run script manually - it works as should. But when CRON runs it - i get just a part of remote output.

I cant realise why its happening.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
pass=123
filelist=$(sshpass -p "$pass" ssh -q -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@"10.10.10.10" "list")

filestring=$(echo "$filelist" | grep -Po "(\S+\s\S+\s+\d+\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4})\slist0\.lst")
filedate=${filestring% list0.lst}
echo $filedate
filestamp=$(date -d "$filedate" +"%s")
echo $filestamp
```

When i get echos in file via CRON - there are date from 0:00:00 - field with date (echo $filedate) is empty. But when i run manually - i get normal date with time...

It really bother me.

Help?

I found solution - add "-tt" to ssh command and all input goes to variable.

```bash
filelist=$(sshpass -p "$pass" ssh -q -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@"10.10.10.10" "list")
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26290994)

Comment: I found some minds that can help topic starter... IDK but i have similar problem and wanna take attention to this question coz author dons answer to comments.